# Type of function

Tags: calculus, functions

Just a curious question about whether a well-known function $f(x)$ exists with the following properties:

- increases exponentially from $0$ up to $x_0,$
- then smoothly drops to a non-zero plateau value $y=a$ with $a>0.$

Comment: Your description is unclear, please show a sktech.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rational functions are useful when you want to customize behavior like this. For the non-zero end behavior, just use the same degree polynomial in the numerator and denominator, with lead coefficients $ax^n$ and $x^n$ respectively. To get a maximum value in a desired spot, try making the denominator function something like a quadratic that gets close to zero there, and then grows again.

For example, suppose you want a maximum near x=5, and an eventual asymptotic value of y=1. Something like $f(x)=\frac{(x-a)^2+b}{(x-5)^2+\frac{1}{10}}$ should work, where you can fiddle around with values of $a$ and $b>0$ to achieve a shape that works for you.

---

More simply, you could just apply graph transformations to $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2+1}$ to move its peak and asymptote where you want them.

---

As for specific, well-known functions, both the normal distribution function and the hyperbolic cosecant have that look, of peaking and then decreasing to a horizontal asymptote.

Comment: If you want it to rise from zero, and the decay to a non-zero value, you might want to use a numerator polynomial of the form $x(x+a)$ for some positive $a$. That's if you don't care what happens when $x<0$.

Comment: Check this one out: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D(sqrt(x%5E4%2B1))%2F((x-5)%5E2%2B1)

Comment: I just gave it an upvote; at least that brings you back up to sea level.